# Worklog filter: show only entries from today, not cumulative for entire issue

Tags: jira, jql

I'm using the jira query `worklogDate >= startOfDay() AND worklogAuthor = currentUser()` to show the items I've logged time with today. It almost works. The problem is that the result shows the summary of all work logged against the task, not just those from today. If I worked on something last week and then again this week the cumulative of all time entries are shown in the filter report.

How to show only the items that were logged today? (or any other time period)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in vanilla Jira. You have a few options though:

1. Create a custom *scripted* field, e.g. 'Time Spent Today' using famous [ScriptRunner for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) add-on. However, there are other scripting add-ons. You can then use this field as a column in your searches.
2. Use a add-on that is capable of what you want to achieve, e.g. [Timesheet Reports and Gadgets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/294/timesheet-reports-gadgets?hosting=server&tab=overview) or more advanced [eazyBI Reports and Charts](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211051/eazybi-reports-and-charts-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview).

However, in both cases you need to be Jira system administrator or you have to ask your Jira admins.